# Ehcache in Spring boot microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, ehcache, distributed-caching

Ehcache works fine in my spring boot app without any problem, but when I run two/more instance of same microservice, data is inconsistent (each spring boot app is having one cache store) how can i implement distributed cache only by using ehcache is it possible ?. Downvoters comments please.
Note : I dont want to use redis database

Comment: 1. Where do you deploy your application? 2. You could start a central Ehcache Server (like Redis) or you could use replication. But the question is more why do you need a cache?

Comment: We have lots of public data and shown in our microservices, we use ehcache for this, to reduce database calls. If anything changes it should reflect in all caches. How can we implement central Ehcache Server.

Comment: Read the docs https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/modules/cache-server.html